# PostKbdMessage for å character within Windows Mobile?

Tags: unicode, windows-mobile

I am trying my best to simulate keyboard input to get å and Å on windows mobile.

Unfortunately WM6 does not support KEYEVENTF_UNICODE and so my challenge begins.

I already tried SendInput, keybd_event, PostMessage, SendMessage and PostKeybdMessage. None of my tries worked. The problem is that most of the APIs only accept VK_ values and there is no VK_ value for the above chars. Using PostKeybdMessage to create æ and ø works fine, but not for å.

Here is the most working code:

```
// http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/accents/codealt.html
BOOL PostRawVKey( UINT vKey, UINT flag )
{
    KEY_STATE_FLAGS kstate[1];
    UINT charbuff[1];
    BOOL bReturn = FALSE;
    HWND hwnd = (HWND)-1;

   switch (flag)
   {
      case VK_SHIFT:
         kstate   [0]   = KeyShiftAnyShiftFlag;
         break;
      case VK_CONTROL:
         kstate   [0]   = KeyShiftAnyCtrlFlag;
         break;
      case VK_MENU://ALT
         kstate   [0]   = KeyShiftAnyAltFlag;
         break;
      case KeyShiftDeadFlag:
          kstate[0] = KeyShiftDeadFlag;
      default:
         kstate   [0]   = KeyStateDownFlag;
         break;
   }

   switch (vKey)
   {
      case VK_RETURN:
         charbuff [0]   = 0x0D;
         break;
      case VK_TAB:
         charbuff [0]   = 0x09;
         break;
      case VK_UP:
         charbuff [0]   = 0x26;
         break;
      case VK_DOWN:
         charbuff [0]   = 0x28;
         break;
      default:
        charbuff [0]    = vKey;
         break;
   }

  if(PostKeybdMessage( hwnd, vKey, kstate[0], 1, &kstate[0], &charbuff[0]) )
  {
      bReturn = TRUE;
//      keybd_event(0,0,m_dwUserDefinedKeySound,0);
  }
  return bReturn; 
}
...
PostRawVKey(L'ä', 0);
PostRawVKey(L'æ', 0);   //  æ=0230 Æ=0198
PostRawVKey(L'°', KeyShiftDeadFlag);
PostRawVKey(L'a', 0);
PostRawVKey(L'ø', 0);   //  ø=0248 Ø=0216
PostRawVKey(L'å', 0);   //  å=0229 or 134, Å=0197   //not OK
...
```

and that is the result showing without any å:

[image: no å input]

I also tried using keybd_event and simulate Alt+134, no success.

Looking at the keyboard messages that are issued when you press the symbol on the soft keyboard, I see:

[image: key messages for tapping å]

```
msg     wParam   lParam
KeyDown VK_CLEAR 0x00000001
CHAR    å 0xe5   0x00000001
KeyUp   VK_CLEAR 0xc0000001
```

and so I also tried

```
SendMessage(hwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_CLEAR, 0x00000001);
SendMessage(hwnd, WM_CHAR, 0x000000e5, 0x00000001);
SendMessage(hwnd, WM_KEYUP, VK_CLEAR, 0xc0000001);
```

Can anyone provide a working example code (c/c++)?

As the Microsoft Keyboard can issue the å, how can I do it?

Background is a keyboard remapper that remaps some keys to danish chars.

Comment: Characters are not virtual keys, WM_CHAR is the way to go.  It isn't clear why you have a problem with it, other than that the window perhaps is not a Unicode window, just try them all.

Comment: As written, WM_CHAR works fine with æ and ø but not for å. So, why does it not work for å? Is that a bug in Windows Mobile? And, yes, the Notes window is a unicode window and it accepts and shows å when I use the software keyboard. Please provide more prof. answers.

Comment: What messages are received by the notepad window when you use `PostRawVKey()`? Are they the same as what you posted for the SIP?

Comment: Yes, I already tried the same sequence I could see with Remote Spy and my Keytest3AK tool with PostMessage and SendMessage (not PostRawVKey()). There was simple no glyph shown in Notes.

Comment: +1 for an interesting question. In your raw data view for Theta, are you using `ø=0248` or `Ø=0216`? If `0216` works and `0248` does not, then `å=0229` could be just beyond the limit of WM (somewhere between `0216` and `0229`).

Comment: Hi jp2code. The interesting thing is that I can enter Alt+0xxx codes for the mentioned chars inside the remote tool MyMobiler form my PC#s keyboard into the Windows Mobile device (notes.exe). I can not test Alt+0xxx on the device as the software keyboard does not proved an ALT key button. And, as I can get all chars using the software keyboard, why does å not work via PostRawVKey()?